# raise 2014 expedition power / running boards

Tags: expedition

Is there anyway I can raise my expedition running boards manually? A fuse blew and there's no electricity going to the board anymore, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not seeing the connection between raising your running boards and a blown fuse.  Why don't you just replace the fuse?  Perhaps you might edit your question so that your issue is more clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some things like that have a square on a shaft to enable it to be turned manually. I suggest you have a look - may even be a "socket" on the gear, motor or shaft end. But if you provided some photos of the system that might help.

Comment: If your fuse is blowing immediately when you install a new one, that means you have a short somewhere you need to resolve.  Could be a power wire that's got the insulation rubbed through and is now contacting the frame, or a plethora of other issues.  Resolve that issue, replace the fuse and things will work normally again.